# Telegram bot hosted in Firebase not responding

Tags: firebase, telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf

I am developing Telegram bot with using Telegraf.js and hosting it using Firebase (as a Function).

When I run it using Firebase Function Emulators on my local everything is fine and working well. But once I deploy the function, it will only work for few minutes and after awhile (like 15+ minutes) it stops responding.

The part I not understand is that, once I create a Firebase Function that will send user a message using chat_id, it'll start responding for a few minutes.

Seems like the bot is not responding after idle for awhile, I super new with Telegram Bot, any articles or hints would really help me right now.

The code would be super basic like

```js
bot.on(['sticker', 'photo'], (ctx) => ctx.reply('Cool! '))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference to this issues: https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/issues/98

I was using polling method (getUpdates) which will cause a timeout issue in Firebase server, I change to using Webhook instead.